# Application for College Inventory Storage Management

Tags: inventory

I am looking for software to use for keeping track of inventory. This isn't for commercial use, I'm not selling the stuff. It is strictly for keeping track of IT storage at a college. Here is a list of what it needs.

It needs to be **free**. It would probably be really difficult to get money for anything regarding storage.

Something that could **be accessed by more than one person at a time** would also be important. We have two storage rooms and administrators who could need access at the same time.

It should have the ability to **create and edit the fields**. I.E. we have a lot of special numbers. It needs the ability to search and sort if possible.

It needs to be **simple**. The back end could be complicated but interns and other people not in the storage department could be using it. We don't want them to break the tables, layout, format. Preferably an add, subtract button for quantities.

The ability to in some way **export it to Excel** is must have.

Feel free to recommend software, websites, or other applications. Also, recommend things if they are only missing a few of the requirements or aren't entirely **free (under $50)**.

Comment: Reading between the lines: it should be a web-app or Windows application, right? So e.g. an Android app would not do?

Comment: Probably not. Its fine if it has a App to go with it but in general it needs workstation access.

Comment: What exactly is “College Inventory Storage Management” and “IT storage at a college”?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) from [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/):

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- From the web site: "LibreOffice Base provides wizards to help users who are new to database design (or just new to the software) to create tables, queries, forms and reports, and it comes supplied with a set of pre-defined table definitions for tracking assets, customers, sales orders, invoices and many other common and useful items."
- Can export to csv, *usable with just about any spreadsheet*, or can link to [Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) which can export xlsx format for Excel *if you don't wish to use [calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) instead*.
- Base comes configured with the full HSQL relational database engine which can be set-up to run in [server mode](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=257585#p257585) so as to allow multiple simultaneous users.
- Can also act as the front end for a wide number of other database back-ends.
- Developers can "lock" forms, queries, etc., to keep inexperienced users out of trouble.

Comment: Would the interns have access to the same user interface as the admins, or a different (locked?) one?

Comment: Interns would need to be restricted. Not necessarily behind a 256-bit encryption. But at least not a easy to get to option that says "Delete Table".